# How to add class from multiple div with class "abcd+n" to another div with class "qwer+n"

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add class from multiple div with class "abcd+n" to another div with class "qwer+n"
for example:

```html
<div class="firstlist">
    <a class="firstlistitem-1" ref="#">link1</a>
    <a class="firstlistitem-2" ref="#">link2</a>
    <a class="firstlistitem-3" ref="#">link3</a>
.........
</div>
and
<div class="secondlist">
    <div class="secondlistitem-1">
        <div class="incorrect">incorrect answer</div>
        <div class="ad_link">CLICK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondlistitem-2">
        <div class="incorrect">incorrect answer</div>
        <div class="ad_link">CLICK</div>
     </div>
    <div class="secondlistitem-3">
        <div class="correct">correct answer</div>
        <div class="ad_link">CLICK</div>
     </div>
.........
</div>
```

On click "CLICK" from "secondlistitem-2" add in "firstlistitem-2" class "incorrect" or "correct"

Comment: To do it with vanilla js you can use the document.querySelector() and .classList property to get the classList of an element and add or remove a class to the element.

Comment: If you are making a quiz, you should consider a totally different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```js
$('.secondlist .ad_linkk').click(function(){
  var cls = $(this).prev('div').attr('class');
  var p = $(this).parent().attr('class').split('-')[1];
  $('.firstlist').find(`a[class*=${p}]`).addClass(cls);
});
```

```css
.incorrect{ color: red }
.correct{ color: green }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstlist">
    <a class="firstlistitem-1" ref="#">link1</a>
    <a class="firstlistitem-2" ref="#">link2</a>
    <a class="firstlistitem-3" ref="#">link3</a>
</div>
<div class="secondlist">
    <div class="secondlistitem-1">
        <div class="incorrect">incorect answer</div>
        <div class="ad_linkk">CLICK</div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondlistitem-2">
        <div class="incorrect">incorect answer</div>
        <div class="ad_linkk">CLICK</div>
     </div>
    <div class="secondlistitem-3">
        <div class="correct">corect answer</div>
        <div class="ad_linkk">CLICK</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is an error if the number of firstlistitem exceeds 10... if i click, for example on item 2, the class is added to all those with 2 digits- 2, 12, 20, 21 etc

Answer (score 1):

You can find the appropriate class to add to the link by seeing if the clicked link has a sibling with `class` `.correct`. If not, the class must be `incorrect`. You can then use the `.index` in the second list of the parent of the link to indicate which of the elements in the first list to highlight:

```js
$('.ad_link').on('click', function() {
  let cc = $(this).siblings('.correct').length ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';
  let index = $(this).parent().index();
  $('.firstlist').children().eq(index).addClass(cc);
});
```

```css
.correct { color : green; }
.incorrect { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstlist">
  <a class="firstlistitem-1" ref="#">link1</a>
  <a class="firstlistitem-2" ref="#">link2</a>
  <a class="firstlistitem-3" ref="#">link3</a>
</div>
<div class="secondlist">
  <div class="secondlistitem-1">
    <div class="incorrect">incorrect answer</div>
    <div class="ad_link">CLICK</div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondlistitem-2">
    <div class="incorrect">incorrect answer</div>
    <div class="ad_link">CLICK</div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondlistitem-3">
    <div class="correct">correct answer</div>
    <div class="ad_link">CLICK</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is soved that
'code'
$('.ad_link').on('click', function() {
let cc = $(this).attr('class');
  let regg = $(this).parents('.secondlistitem').index();
  $('.firstlist').find(".firstlistitem-" + (regg+1)).addClass(cc);

});
'code'

Comment: @DanIurcu I'm glad you got it working. Since the code is different to either answer, you could post it as an answer yourself (you can accept your own answer).